# Как программно открыть порт в Брендмауэре (WinXP SP3)

Tags: c#

Добрый день.
Как программно (при помощи C#) открыть порт в Брендмауэре (WinXP SP3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Статья](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/securitytools/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c)
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​